# Cannot Delete Corrupted B2C Application and Tenant

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am at Microsoft Azure training and was following instructions in a lab for demonstrating a B2C application log in through MSA provider.

Upon completing the lab, the functionality did not work as expected, so I attempted to adjust things to fix it.  But, now I am stuck with a corrupt B2C application (d35ecfbf-f1ef-40ec-b865-ffebaa9a70fb), which cannot be deleted or edited by any means.  This has also locked up my entire B2C tenant (32a2a302-3440-4e5d-ad9d-bd7413d71aac), which cannot be deleted either.

I found [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureadb2c/2016/09/09/known-issue-b2c-app-mgmt/) explaining that this is a known issue and to post on Stack Overflow for guidance in deleting the corrupt app and tenant.  So, here I am.

The app does not show up in the ARM portal.  In ASM portal, it shows up, but cannot be edited or deleted.  Via PowerShell, the app is visible, but cannot be edited or deleted.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you created all the components in one (training) Resource Group you can try to delete that group.

Comment: How did you create that corrupted app?

Comment: @JeroenHeier Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe Azure AD tenants (and associated registered apps) exist above and outside of Resource Groups.  So there is no association that I can find.

Comment: @Saca This was done using Part 4 of [this lab](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-solutions-digital-marketing-reference-implementation/blob/master/labs/Lab2-Security.md).

I believe I had a typo in my URL for the app in the apps.dev.microsoft.com registration (task 11 in part 4 of lab), so I went back to adjust it, and it was either at that point the app became corrupted, or when I may have deleted the registration from that location to recreate it that it became corrupted.

Comment: Go back to apps.dev.microsoft.com and delete it from there, then you should be able to delete the tenant

Comment: What credentials did you sign in with to that portal btw? Your B2C credentials or some other credentials?

Comment: @Saca It's already gone from apps.dev.microsoft.com, but it still exists in Azure and can't be edited or deleted.  

I signed in with my MSA and navigated to the B2C tenant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue with 2 B2C applications. After creating an Azure support ticket, Microsoft support told me that the problem is that the ServicePrincipals for these B2C (V2 converged endpoint) Applications were deleted. So you need to recreate the ServicePrincipal, like this:

New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId "app-id"

On the first try, I received an error message (Error reading JToken from JsonReader), but after a second try it worked.

Next, log in to the Azure Portal with an account that has Global administrator permissions in the Directory. Now go to the B2C Features Blade and you should be able to delete the B2C application.

Log of with this account and log back on with another account that has permissons on the Directory. Go to the Azure Active Directoy Blade and remove the "extra" Global Admin user from the AD, so that only your current user account is left. Now delete the Directory.

This worked for me, I hope it helps!
Regards, Lennart

Comment: This worked!  I used the Rm cmdlet instead, since I had already logged in as such, and it worked beautifully.

New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId **APPGUID**

Thank you so much!